# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installation failed, sql100exception on sqlenginedbstartconfigaction_install_configrc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on Win XP Sp3 machine (with .net 3.5 sp1, .net 4) and getting this exception (after ~20 installations on similar configurations in the last two weeks):

```
EventType : sql100exception     P1 : sql server 2008 r2@rtm@     P2 : 0xe53883a0
P3 : 0xe53883a0     P4 : 0xbe03358b@1306@24     P5 : 0xbe03358b@1306@24     
P6 : sqlenginedbstartconfigaction_install_configrc     P7 : 0x9396de01     
P8 : unknown     P9 : unknown     P10 : unknown
```

After this message setup continues, but at the end the SQL SErver services failed to install and I got error message again (check logs,...).

I tried several times completely removing the SQL Server installation, deleting the directories and every keys in registry named like `Microsoft Sql Server`, `MSSQL`, etc, checked permission for `Software\Microsoft\PCHealth\ErrorReporting\DW\Installed` registry, deleted msxml 4.0 sp2 processor, checked if temp directory is encrypted, checked gpedit...

Here are log files:

Detail: http://pastebin.com/tPvwFr13 (last part), https://hotfile.com/dl/234829785/be9cfdb/Detail3.txt.html (full file)

Summary: http://pastebin.com/xn4VwdFx

Summary Global Rules: http://pastebin.com/N3XEtMUV

Comment: Most users will be hesitant to download a file from file sharing site. I would suggest to use sites like Pastebin.com instead of Hotfile so users can simply view text instead of downloading a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Sql Server Database Engine Service Account to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Service Configuration setup step). Installation completed without errors and it works.

Usually, I select NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Service Account, but for the current configuration SYSTEM account should work.